# Why don't some shellcode in PicoCTF Shellz work even though it means the same as those which do?

Tags: linux, shell, assembly

I am trying to understand the shellcode solution to this [CTF problem](https://github.com/xennygrimmato/picoctf-writeups/blob/master/2017/level-2/shellz/shellz.md).

```
0:  31 c9                   xor    ecx,ecx
2:  f7 e1                   mul    ecx
4:  b0 0b                   mov    al,0xb
6:  51                      push   ecx
7:  68 2f 2f 73 68          push   0x68732f2f
c:  68 2f 62 69 6e          push   0x6e69622f
11: 89 e3                   mov    ebx,esp
13: cd 80                   int    0x80
```

My understanding of the shellcode is as follows:

1. ecx is set to 0.
2. eax *= ecx, so eax = 0
3. The lower 8 bits of eax (ie al) is set to 0xb : opcode for execve().
4. "/bin//sh" is pushed to the stack. Its pointer is put in ebx ([first argument](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscall.2.html) of execve).
5. int 0x80 is the syscall interrupt. We run execve("/bin//sh") and the shell is open for us to use.

The arch seems to be i386 the way the registers are named. Definitely 32 bits.

What I do not understand is as follows:

1. Why is it when I replace `mul ecx` with `mov eax, 0x0` or `xor eax, eax`, the shell does not spawn? Don't they all set eax to 0? When I  replaced only `xor ecx, ecx` with `mov ecx, 0x0` and it worked fine.
2. When I replaced `mov al, 0xb` with `mov eax, 0xb`, it worked fine. But when I subsequently removed `mul ecx`, it didnt work anymore. Why is `mul ecx` necessary? If I change the entire eax value to 0xb, doesn't that mean i dont need to set it to 0 first? I'm guessing the original shellcode has to because it only sets the lower 8 bits of eax to 0xb (`mov al, 0xb`). So the higher 24 bits needs to be 0.

Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: mul ecx also sets edx to 0. edx is the third parameter to execve.

Comment: Why is there a double / in the string? Without it the string would be naturally null-terminated.

Comment: @prl that's probably the point, to avoid zero byte in payload's machine code, so the payload can be delivered as null terminated string. Then again I would probably use single slash + junk at end, and overwrite junk with `mov [esp+3],cl` after first `push`.

Comment: `mul ecx` is a neat trick for zeroing two more registers with only 2 bytes of machine code!  I'll have to remember that for [code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/78896/compute-the-adler-32-checksum/78972#78972).  Although often, `xor eax,eax` / `cdq` to get two zeroed regs is enough.  (And `lea ecx, [eax+1]` to get small constants in other regs in 3 bytes).  But yeah, here you need `ecx` and `edx` zeroed to take advantage of Linux's handling of `argv` and `envp` where it treats NULL as the same as pointer-to-NULL, i.e. an empty list instead of returning `-EFAULT`.